# How to install 3to2? Windows 8 64 bit

Tags: python

I downloaded 3to2, but I have no idea on how to install it. Any advice would be great. I'm very new to this sort of thing, which is why I've been having a lot of trouble

Comment: Why do you want to install 3to2? Maybe it is better to use Python 2.7?

Comment: My code is for python 3 currently and I don't know any other way to convert it

Comment: so, why you are not using just  Python 3.0.1? You don't know how to install python plugins, so have a look there (installing a plugin is easy):  https://docs.python.org/2/install/ https://docs.python.org/3/install/